# How to call More than one CollectionView in collection View data Source on table view cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have 2 collection view in table view cells and each collection view has Outlet in own table view cell . how i can call and use this two collection view in `cellForItemAt` method in view controller.

> if (collectionView == self.amazing_Collection) // doesnt work

this is table view methods in view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let section = indexPath.section  
    if section == 0 {
         let cell0  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) as! searchCell
         return cell0

          }else if section == 1 {
            let cell1  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "slideCell", for: indexPath) as! slideCell
```

return cell0

and this is collection view method for fill image and labels

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
   "amazingCollecionCell", for: indexPath) as! amazingCollecionCell
       ////this is work correctly
            return cell

```
return cell 

        //here iwant to say if this collection view execute under lines  
        let cell_Just_Here = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "justhereproductscell", for: indexPath) as! JustHereProductsCell
        //lable fill



        return cell_Just_Here
    }
}
```

Comment: A single tableview cell contains two collection views or there are two tableviewcells and both contains single collection view, Which one is it in your scenario?

Comment: there is two table view cell collectioncview outlet inside there and two collection view cells for image and label outlet

Answer (score 0):

When tableview's data source method is called, set the collection view's `tag` value as `indexPath.row`(cell's index path). By this in the collection view's datasource method you will be able to identify the collection view with the tag value and set the cells accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add your code in the question related to your question.